# How to add Leading zero/zeros in azure logic app for the variable?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, zero

Ideally, there should be 6 digits in a variable called 'subject'

"how to fill the 0 if not 6digit in the subject variable?"

```
example *subject = 387592(continue the process)
        *subject = 35885(add zero to make 6digit = 035885)
        *subject = 7161( add zeros 007161)
```

> python zfill(6) helps to solve this kind of issues

Answer (score 3):

An old school string parsing approach should do the trick:

```
substring(concat('000000',variables('IntString4')),sub(length(concat('000000',variables('IntString4'))),6),6)
```

Here's the breakdown:

1. Concat the existing string with leading zeros

   concat('000000',variables('IntString4')
2. Measure the length of the string and subtract the desired length to calculate the starting index of the eventual substring:

   sub(length(concat('000000',variables('IntString4'))),6)
3. Use substring to capture the last 6 characters:

   substring(#1,#2,6)

You could make this a bit more readable and dynamic with variables, but same logic applies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "formatNumber" function?

For example, in your case

- formatNumber('35885', '000000') -> Result "035885"
- formatNumber('7161', '000000') -> Result "007161"

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatNumber

Comment: first parameter to `formatNumber` is either `int` or `double`. And you are trying to pass `string`. This is not going to work.

Comment: Use number as first parameter and you get the expected result.